# set user foreign key default value as superuser or admin on on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT

Tags: python, django, django-models

As I was using `on_delete=models.CASCADE` with `currentOwner` in the `asset` model, whenever I deleted any user, all the assets owned by that user were getting deleted. I want the asset to be transferred to the superuser/admin. So I tried `# MY SOLUTION` but it is throwing me an error:

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'admin'.
```

I think deleting previous migrations and running makemigrations and migrate commands might help, but that will probably erase all the data in the database, which I do not want to happen.
Here are my User and asset models:

```
class User(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True, )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=32)
    gender_choices = [("M", "Male"), ("F", "Female"), ("O", "Others")]
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices, default="M", max_length=1)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email", "gender"]
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    objects = User_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class asset(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, null=False)
    asset_type = models.ForeignKey('assetType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True) #unique=True
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    purchase_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True)
    currentOwner = models.ForeignKey(User, default=User.objects.get(is_superuser=True).id, null=False, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT) # MY SOLUTION
```

Is there any way this can be solved?

Comment: can you put the whole error trace

Comment: Write `default=User.objects.get(is_superuser=True).pk` also It will fetch only first object or instance.

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey, you are wrong. If you have more than 1 superuser, you receive Error in server start. If you don't have a superuser, you receive Error on server start!!!

Comment: @MaximDanilov Well then we can use `get_object_or_404()` or `Model.DoesNotExist` exception as used by you. The main thing I was telling to use `pk` only.

Comment: Say I don't create more than one admin, my real question here is why am I getting this ValueError even though I'm using  ```.get(is_superuser=True).id``` This statement should pass the value of id, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was deleting all migrations except the first one, and then running makemigraions and migrate command. Since we never deleted the database, we never lost our records.

Answer (score 0):

I read documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET in example you can find your case.

if you don't want to read documentation, the short answer:

For foreign key you should use `on_delete=models.SET`.
AS argument `models.SET` get a function name.

in your case:

```
def get_superuser():
    su_user = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).first()  # if you have more than 1 superuser, this get the first in list.
    if su_user:
        return su_user
    raise DoesNotExist('Please add Super User')  # or you can create SU here

class asset(models.Model):
    ... # any staff here
    currentOwner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET(get_superuser))
```

Comment: I am still facing the same error. ```@Maxim Danilov```

Comment: @ShashankTiwari - i improve the answer

Comment: you just removed pk from the return statement!

Comment: i change models.SET_DEFAULT to models.SET